# Incremnting division in python

Tags: python, increment, division

I am new and I need to know whether it is possible to increment division the same way you can increment addition or subtraction in python. Thank you!

Comment: What do you call "incrementing addition"? Can you give an example?

Comment: What do you mean with "increment"? `x//`? That will not work, but `x /= 2.3` will work.

Answer (score -1):

If by `incrementing addition` you mean `+=` then, of course yes, it is available for all the arithmetic operators...

```py
a = 100
a //= 9
print(a)
```

Output:-

> 11

```py
b = 1024
b /= 2
print(b)
```

Output:-

> 512.0